# How do I move just the files with a particular extension from nested sub-directories?

Tags: bash

In a directory I have many sub-directories and each of these sub-directories have many files of different types. I want to extract all the files with a particular extension from each subdirectory and put it in a different folder. Is it possible to write a bash script to do this? If so how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have bash v4 and have

```
shopt -s globstar
```

in your .profile, you can use:

```
mv ./sourcedir/**/*.ext ./targetdir
```

Comment: this also works in zsh.  in fact, it has worked since i remember (like last ten years?), in the default configuration as far as i can tell.

Answer (score 10):

```
$ find <directory> -name '*.foo' -exec mv '{}' <other_directory> \;
```

`find` does a recursive search through a directory structure and performs the given actions on any files it finds that match the search criteria.

In this case, `-name '*.foo'` is the search criteria, and `-exec mv '{}' <other_directory> \;` tells `find` to *execute* `mv` on any files it finds, where `'{}'` is converted to the filename and `\;` represents the end of the command.

Comment: i thought there needs to be some loop which will go over all the subdirectories. I am a total novice at bash scripting

Comment: `man find` will teach you about the `find` command (in this case will find all *.foo files (and dirs) in all subdirectories, and for each one will run (-exec) the command `mv found_filename.foo other_directory`

Answer (score 2):

Using find and a simple while loop whould do it:

```
find directory -name '*.foo'|while read file; do
    mv $file other_directory/
done
```

Here it will move all files with a `.foo` suffix to other_directory/

Answer (score 1):

You can use *find* and *xargs* to reduce the need for loops or multiple calls to *mv*.

```
find /path/to/files -type f -iname \*foo -print0 |
    xargs -0 -I{} mv {} /path/to/other/dir
```